# Linker Error using g++ with Qt 4.5.1

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm trying to test out a new dev environment and I am having some problems referencing some of the required Qt libraries.

First I ran this:

```
$ g++ HelloWorld.C -o HelloWorld -I /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.5.1/include/QtCore/ -I /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.5.1/include/
```

and got this error:

```
    /tmp/ccmsm4kZ.o: In function `QString::QString(char const*)':
HelloWorld.C:(.text._ZN7QStringC2EPKc[_ZN7QStringC5EPKc]+0x1d): undefined reference to `QString::fromAscii_helper(char const*, int)'
/tmp/ccmsm4kZ.o: In function `QString::~QString()':
HelloWorld.C:(.text._ZN7QStringD2Ev[_ZN7QStringD5Ev]+0x2d): undefined reference to `QString::free(QString::Data*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So then I  added reference to the QtCore library via:

```
$ g++ HelloWorld.C -o HelloWorld -I /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.5.1/include/QtCore/ -I /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.5.1/include/ -L /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.5.1/lib -lQtCore
```

which removed the compile errors, however when I try to run the program I get this error:

```
./HelloWorld: error while loading shared libraries: libQtCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I wasn't able to find a solution for this problem via google. Anyone have advice?

Comment: the libraries are not in the path your os is searching. either put the libs in the standard path or make your path visible for the os, using the `export` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error indicates that while the linker can find the library at compilation, it can't find it during runtime.

You should update your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include that location like this:

In `~.bashrc` probably somewhere near the bottom:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.5.1/lib`

Alternatively, if you want to make this persistent throughout your system (and have root access), you can make an entry in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` (on RedHat, I'm not sure about the other distributions)

`touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/qt.conf`

Add the path to this file, and then update your runtime via `/sbin/ldconfig`

Comment: And yet another way is by adding `QMAKE_RPATHDIR += $ORIGIN` to the .pro file, which will make the executable search for .so files in the same directory as the executable is.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Worked like a charm!

Comment: The `RPATH` option works especially good to deploy an executable on other systems, where you may not want to require someone to change his global `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `ldconfig`.